# visual basic save informations as txt

Tags: vb.net

I have written a small tool so I do not have to write an email every day.
I have to say that unfortunately I have not very much experience in VB, but it bravely waage, possibly someone is
So nice and helps me, I would really really look very happy.

The problem is:

I send an e-mail to the transport service provider GLS with a seal number every day shortly before the end of the event
And the number of respective pallets. I would love a kind of pallet account either as text or even
With small Gui. It would have to be sent whenever an e-mail is sent to the files paralell as a txt file
Saved (to be appended in a new line) with the associated date.
Unfortunately, I do not really get it. Really good would be if you use the whole instead of using Excel or the editor
Also still read out in the mini program.

Here is my source code:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles senden.Click

Dim Msg As New MailMessage
Dim myCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
myCredentials.UserName = "*********"
myCredentials.Password = "*********"

Msg.IsBodyHtml = False

Dim mySmtpsvr As New SmtpClient()
mySmtpsvr.EnableSsl = True 'SSL aktivieren
mySmtpsvr.Host = "smtp.strato.de"
mySmtpsvr.Port = 587

mySmtpsvr.UseDefaultCredentials = False
mySmtpsvr.Credentials = myCredentials

Try
Msg.From = New MailAddress("*********")
ProgressBar1.Value = 10
Msg.To.Add("*********")
Msg.CC.Add(ccempfaender.Text)
ProgressBar1.Value = 20
Msg.Subject = "Plombennummer für Wechselbrücke Kundennummer: *********"
ProgressBar1.Value = 30
Msg.Body = "Hallo, wir möchten Ihnen die heutige Plombennummer mitteilen, diese lautet: " & (Plombennummer.Text) & ". Außerdem haben wir auf der Wechselbrücke folgende Anzahl an Paletten: " & "Europaletten: " & (Euro.Text) & ", Einwegpaletten: " & (Einweg.Text) & " verladen. Über eine schnelle Abwicklung würden wir uns sehr freuen und verbleiben mit den besten Grüßen! Panorama24 Lagerteam. Für dringliche Fragen, stehen wir Ihnen gerne unter folgender Rufnummer zur Verfügung: *********"
ProgressBar1.Value = 80
mySmtpsvr.Send(Msg)
ProgressBar1.Value = 100
MsgBox("Erfolgreich - schönen Feierabend", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Information")
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(Err.Number & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace.ToString) 'Falls ein Fehler auftritt wird eine MsgBox angezeigt
End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

[image: the form designer]

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's stream writer class to log your data [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)